# In Indian politics , how many parties are present currently

Tags: parties, india

I want to know how many political parties there are in India. Can't there only be two parties, the ruling party and the opposition party, like there are in the United States?

Comment: Question appears to be off-topic because it is about Wikipedia reference

Answer (score 3):

Depending on how/what you count, there's between 50 and 1600 parties in India:

- **Total Registered Parties 1616**
- National Parties 6
- State Parties 47
- Unrecognized Parties 1563

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_political_parties_in_India

As such, there clearly can be more than two parties. There are governments with one party, two parties, and multiple parties.

FYI, the US has a multi-party system, but typically is dominated by only two.